# How to backup and restore SharePoint sub site and list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How to backup and restore SharePoint sub site?
How to backup and restore SharePoint list?
How to do granular backup in SharePoint?

Comment: Are you handling SharePoint online or SharePoint On-Premise?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full post on my blog in facebook. Click [here](https://www.facebook.com/notes/isharepoint/sharepoint-backuprestore-export-a-sub-site-or-list/2875597492559211/?av=943711255747854&eav=AfbgH6pPt3yYlmor36E7RoB_zHr_WsROt7pi3b5X7i_3FEc2MNjU611gQQLcbAReAUE)